# How to create Stripe plans instead of prices?

Tags: stripe-payments

So I have my clients app set up to work with plans, which I was testing with my account. I set those test plans a couple months back, but now that I'm setting it up on my client's account, when I create a product I can only create a price for it. Did something change. Can I create a plan or do I have to change my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prices are a new abstraction that replace Plans, yes :

https://stripe.com/docs/billing/prices-guide

https://stripe.com/docs/billing/migration/migrating-prices

They're created by default in the dashboard now.

You shouldn't need to change any of your code though, it's completely backwards and forwards compatible.

You can simply pass a `price_xxx` ID into anything that takes a `plan` parameter, for example, code that creates a subscription and sets `items[0].plan=price_xxx` will just work. You'll also see that the API mirrors the Price into both `plan` and `price` fields when you read an object from the API so again, your code doesn't need to know a Price is being used.

[image]